# .pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.13.5/lib/src/base_request.dart:144:7: Error: The getter 'Lrethrow' isn't defined for the class 'BaseRequest'

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Trying to compile my flutter project. It trow an error and exit. It look like it's cause by http. But i don't know how solve it. My flutter version is 3.3.6. Sorry for the english.
[image]
My error
[image]
My dependencies

Comment: try updating your dependencies, then run `flutter clean` followed by `flutter pub get`.

Comment: I have already tried but no results

Comment: you may check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74156104/glibc-2-33-not-found-while-building-flutter-for-linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP paquage version. I have updated the package and clean the app